# need to find modifyall permission for all profiles and for all objects

Tags: soql

I am unable to figure out the relation between the objects. I want to extract modifyall permission for all the available user profiles for all objects(standard and custom).
I tried using the query

```
 SELECT Assignee.Name, PermissionSet.Id,
 PermissionSet.isOwnedByProfile, PermissionSet.Profile.Name,
 PermissionSet.Label FROM PermissionSetAssignment WHERE PermissionSetId
 IN (SELECT ParentId FROM ObjectPermissions WHERE SObjectType =
 'Account' AND PermissionsRead = true)
```

But it is unable to fulfill the criteria. Also the above query does not return the profile name insted it is returning  `[object Object]` for the column  `PermissionSet.Profile.Name` in the query

[image: Kindly suggest if there is any other] Kindly suggest if there is any other way to solve this problem!

Or if we can write a query to extract table with fields like :
`Profile Name` `sObject` `PermissionRead` `PermissionModifyAllRecords` etc.

Thankyou

Comment: try to run this query in Developer console and use debug to print your result. They will give you proper output.

Comment: This can be useful : https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2012/06/using-soql-to-determine-your-users-permissions-2.html

Comment: @HSdev , I followed the same link for this query

Comment: @SaumyaGaikwad, Okay !! if you are familiar with workbench then do generate your query from there as well. might be it can be solve your problem

Comment: @SaumyaGaikwad Workbench : https://www.salesforce.com/blog/2011/12/permission-sets-best-practice-mass-assign-permission-sets-and-other-cool-things-using-the-api.html

Comment: @HSdev , Thankyou. The problem to [sObject][sObject] resolved through workbench.

Comment: @SaumyaGaikwad, Great !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you go for more than 2 level it will display as [object.object] than its value in developer console query.

If you are interested only on profile then try the below,

```
SELECT Profile.Name from PermissionSet  WHERE Id
 IN (SELECT ParentId FROM ObjectPermissions WHERE SObjectType = 'Account' AND PermissionsRead = true)
```

Comment: i already tried working with this. This works perfect, but i have to execute query separately for every sObject. Is it possible to get permission for all sObjects?

Answer (score 1):

I think it might help you.

```
List<PermissionSetAssignment> lst = [SELECT Assignee.Name, PermissionSet.Id, PermissionSet.isOwnedByProfile, PermissionSet.Profile.Name, PermissionSet.Profile.Id,
 PermissionSet.Label, PermissionSet.Name 
 FROM PermissionSetAssignment WHERE PermissionSetId 
 IN (SELECT ParentId FROM ObjectPermissions WHERE PermissionsRead = true)];

System.debug(JSON.serialize(lst));
```

Comment: It does not fulfill the criteria. i want permission corresponding to **sObject**, not `Assignee.Name`